# Why is this deadlocking?

Tags: jpa, javafx, deadlock

Hi I am running into a deadlock in a JavaFX Application and I am not sure why this is happening...
When initializing my application I start a Thread to load a certain view that is creating an object that is extending my DatabaseManager. At the same time another Thread is doing the same on another view and another object that is extending the DatabaseManager.

The first thread that enters the following constructor enters the synchronized block but NEVER reaches the "System.out.println("****3");" line.
After this happened my later started thread enters the constructor and is of course blocked since the resource has never been released again.
by thread 1. 
Any ideas, why this is resulting in a deadlock? I am using javafx.concurrent.Task with java.lang.Thread

```
public abstract class DatabaseManager {

protected static final AtomicReference<EntityManager> entityManager = new AtomicReference<>();

protected DatabaseManager() {
    if (entityManager.get() == null) {
                System.out.println("****1");
        synchronized (entityManager) {
            if (entityManager.get() == null) {
                System.out.println("****2");
                entityManager.set(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                        DatabaseConstants.hsqlPersistenceUnitName,
                        DatabaseConstants.getProperties()).createEntityManager());
                System.out.println("****3");
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`AtomicReference`s (and their primitive wrapper friends) manage their own atomicity. So, while I can't really see why this is deadlocking, using a synchronized block to use an `AtomicReference` defeats the entire purpose of the `AtomicReference` in the first place.

You can just do:

```
protected DatabaseManager() {
    entityManager.compareAndSet(null, 
         Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
             DatabaseConstants.hsqlPersistenceUnitName,
             DatabaseConstants.getProperties()).createEntityManager());
}
```

which will have exactly the same effect as what you are trying to do (without the logging, obviously).

The recommended way to lazily initialize a static field is to use the "Lazy initialization holder class idiom":

```
public abstract class DatabaseManager {

    protected static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EntityManagerHolder.entityManager ;
    }

    private static class EntityManagerHolder {
        static final EntityManager entityManager = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                DatabaseConstants.hsqlPersistenceUnitName,
                DatabaseConstants.getProperties()).createEntityManager() ;
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures lazy initialization, because the inner class `DatabaseManager.EntityManagerHolder` is not loaded until it is referenced for the first time, which doesn't happen until `getEntityManager()` is called for the first time. It is guaranteed atomic, because class initializers are guaranteed atomic. And furthermore, since the atomicity is enforced only when the inner class is initialized, the cost of synchronization is not incurred on subsequent calls to `getEntityManager()`. (By contrast, the solution with the `AtomicReference` performs a (presumably internally-synchronized) call to `AtomicReference.compareAndSet(...)` each time you create a new `DatabaseManager`.)

See Josh Bloch's *Effective Java*, item 71, for a fuller discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my deadlock eventhough I do not know why this results in a deadlock...
I have just another thread that is trying to access another database. The application interacts with 2 databases. All performings on my HSQL database came from my DatabaseManager and while one thread was trying to initialize the EntityManager in my DatabaseManager the third Thread was simply calling

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(DBConstants.ORACLE_PERSISTENCE_UNIT).createEntityManager();
```

After removing that line and also using the DatabaseManager to establish the connection to the second database the deadlock was gone.
But I have no idea why. The only possible solution in my eyes is that eclipselink itself deadlocked there...